# How to have blank/null for AutoInc field in FireDAC for new record instead of negative number?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, firedac

By default, FireDAC uses negative numbers for AutoInc field for new records not yet posted to the database. How do you get the AutoInc field to be null and therefore show blank on a dbgrid?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't touch those values (by some code hacking, as there seems to be no setting for this). Instead I would write the `OnGetText` handler for that field and return an empty string for negative values.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: If the field is of TFDAutoIncField type, then set ClientAutoIncrement to False.

Comment: @da-soft Thanks but that did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is setting the field's property DefaultExpression = Null and it work.Works for me.

Source: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firedac/integerfield-default-value-1/2001860